# Source Control in VSCode is not refreshed automatically

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, source-control-explorer

I have updated Mac OS from Sierra to Monterey recently. Since then I have been facing some issues. One of them is in VSCode, when I do changes to the files the changes are not reflected in Source Control or Explorer until the refresh button is clicked manually in Source Control Tab. Can anyone help me out to solve this issue?

I have `git 2.16` installed in my machine. 
I have updated the version of VSCode and `git.autorefresh` is set to true.

Update 1:
I have reinstalled git. Now I have `git 2.35.1`. But still, the `Source Control` tab is not auto refreshed.

Comment: This is a bug in vscode. The related issues are these: [64775](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64775) (closed),  [42821](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/42821) (closed) and  [5970](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/5970) (open as of May 2022).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had my project in `/System/Volumes/Data/<my-folder-name>`. After moving to `/Users/<user-id>/`, it started working. I even created a simple project in both the folders and tested them. Project in the former path faces the issue whereas the latter one doesn't face any issue. So I moved my work to the `Users` folder but I don't know the root cause.

Comment: I faced the same issue, in my case I had special characters in folder's name, after changed it, it worked just fine after a vs code restart.

Comment: I have the same problem. My folders structure is: //wsl.localhost/Ubuntu-20.04/home/username/project - Could it be that the dot is causing the problem here? But I can't change the name of my wls folder...

Comment: klediooo same issue here

Answer (score 10):

As Visual Studio Code "Version Control" page mentions:

> Note: VS Code will leverage your machine's Git installation, so you need to install Git first before you get these features. Make sure you install at least version 2.0.0.

So first of all make sure you have installed git on your machine([GIT FOR macOS](https://git-scm.com/download/mac)).

Then

- Open the command palette in vscode(In mac,Press ‘’`Cmd + Shift + P`’’):
- Type "`open settings`"
- choose "Open Settings (JSON)

In the setting.json file, add the following flag for auto-refreshing: `"git.autorefresh": true,`

Then save the changes.
your problem should be solved.

In addition, There are more git config that you can use them(just type git in setting.json file for more options)

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have git installed already versioned 2.16 and even git.autorefresh is set to true. But still I face this issue.

Comment: Thanks! Adding `"git.autorefresh": true,` worked for me :)

Comment: Worked for me, Ubuntu 22.10 arm64 VScode 1.76.0. **Make sure to reload your VScode after you add the setting in the json** otherwise you will be scratching your head thinking what the heck that did.

Comment: This worked... but gotta be the dumbest thing that VScode doesn't do this automagically

Comment: This does NOT work for me. I am running debian 11.4.

Comment: related: [Why don't other programs see the changes I made to a file in VS Code until I save those changes?](/q/76984829/)

Answer (score 5):

Even though my setting in 'Open Default Settings (JSON)' had `"git.autorefresh": true,` I also had to add this to 'Open User Settings (JSON)' and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when I staged/unstaged parts of a file, it would not update before I switched to another window and back again. I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Git 2.34.1 and vscode 1.74.3. I set this config in vscode:

```
"git.closeDiffOnOperation": true
```

Edit: Unfortunately this only works on my desktop and not my laptop, even though they both run the same ubuntu, git and vscode.

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to happen in different versions for different reasons. As of April 2023, I solved it by cmd + p -> "git: open repository" -> select your main git repository. Probably because I opened a subfolder only instead of the main one with git.