# How can I make VS Code not restore open editors from files external to the workspace folder(s) upon reopening the workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I added a folder to workspace in VS Code, how to make it so if I edit a file or folder that's not from the workspace folder, this window/tab should not show up when I restart VS Code. Only the files opened from the workspace folder should reopen after I restart my VS Code.

Here is my settings.json:

```json
{
    "files.hotExit": "off",
    "window.restoreWindows": "none",

    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "files.saveConflictResolution": "overwriteFileOnDisk",
    "explorer.autoReveal": false,
    "window.openFilesInNewWindow": "on",
    "workbench.editor.enablePreview": false,
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "files.restoreUndoStack": false,
}
```

Here's what I want: Only files on the workspace folder gets reopened next time I restart VS Code. Files or Folder from any other place should not be reopened after restart

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of there being a way to do this- at least- not without any extensions. Hot Exit is for files with *unsaved changes*.

I tried to think of a way to hack it with a keybinding and no extensions (by hardcoding a large number of "iterations" over entries of the Open Editors view and checking whether the resource is in the workspace), but I'm stumped (not sure how to check if a resource is part of a workspace with a [when clause](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts)).

You're probably best off looking for an extension or creating one yourself. Or you could [raise a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.